# How to customize problem description in VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I want to add a json schema to my vscode-extension, which will be provided to other users.

After I add it to `package.json`, which is the following part

```
{
  "contributes": {
    "jsonValidation": [
      {
        "fileMatch": "/*.target.json",
        "url": "./target_schema.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I find that the regex pattern will be hard to understand for a normal user.

[image: String does not match the regex pattern]

How to customize the problem description?
In this case, instead of telling the user regex pattern, tell the user `Use Hex value.`

I guess that VSCode tasks and problem-matcher may contain some solutions, but I haven't found a good example.

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html. Very loosely related (about a specific validation library- not VS Code): https://stackoverflow.com/q/72771355/11107541 (using a schema property that is not standard to JSON Schema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40274361/13230147), we can know that

> Custom error messages are not supported in the standard JSON Schema.

However, many validators provide their own way to customize error messages.

We can check the [Contribution Points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#Configuration-property-schema) in the official website to get the provided method in the VSCode. It uses `patternErrorMessage` to customize error messages.

[image: The custom error messages result]